# Extract float from a printf output where it is formated as %d

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I see a huge number getting printed on doing the below. The problem is I have the output and the source code corresponding to it, but unable to extract the actual value.

One method I tried was to first convert these numbers to hex [here](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_signed_int.html) and then convert the hex to float [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). But I donot see the value in expected range. Any other suggested alternatives?

**Note:** I donot have control over the source code, so I cannot do the change in source code. I need to extract the information needed from available output. I am well aware that %f is for float and the %d has cropped up due to a typo

**Code**:

```
float float1 float2;
.
.
.
printf("Current value float1=%d float2 = %d",float1,float2);
```

**Output**:

```
Current value float1=-1065244909 float2 = 536870912
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just fix the code to use the correct format specifier ?

Comment: You **cannot** use `%d` with `float` arguments. The values you are seeing are not the float variables. They are garbage. Different garbage depending on compiler and architecture. If you want to interpret the bits of your floats as integers, do it properly with a union or `memcpy`.

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` on your platform ? If it's not 4 then then you're not going to have much luck and your only option will be to fix the code and try again.

Comment: both are int and float are 4 bytes

Comment: Any way decimal would be lost, so you can never print float with decimal

Comment: @PaulR Anyway a `float` argument passed to a variadic function is promoted to `double`, so it does not matter what the size of `float` is. The mismatch in the code in the question is between the `%d` format and an argument that has been promoted to `double` before being passed to the function.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for something impossible and, even if it weren't, any answer would only be applicable in contexts of deep insanity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `sizeof(int) = sizeof(float) == 4` on your platform, and that your ABI passes `int` and `float` values to `printf` in the same way, then it looks like your two values would be:

```
-1065244909 = 0xC081A713 = -4.051645
  536870912 = 0x20000000 =  1.0842022E-19
```

Comment: I think -1065244909 = 0xc081a713 rather than 0x7fffffff

Comment: @mc110: thanks - my bad (operator error with calculator!) - fixed now.

Comment: I did get these values using conversion tools I mentioned in the question. But 1.0842022E-19 is not in my expected range. Hence, I posted this question of any alternative conversion formulae. gmake is used for compilation.

Comment: Note that `1.0842022E-19` is a very small number - close enough to 0.0 that it may be considered to be equal to 0.0 - is 0 in your expected range ?

Comment: Thanks.I guess 0 will be printed as is.. Also, negative numbers are out of my range

Comment: OK - it may just be that the values are bogus and you will have to fix the bug and try again.

Comment: unfortunately, may b yes. However, it would have been nice had %d had just resulted in truncation rather than this garbling.

Comment: The C standard **mandates** that `float`s are promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`. On the other hand, it does not mandate that they are passed on the stack or in the same registers that `int`s would be passed.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: good point - I wonder if the two int values can be concatenated and interpreted as a double ?

Comment: @PaulR That is what I would expect when the ABI uses the stack for argument-passing. My OS uses floating-point registers (even when passing arguments to `printf`), so that if I compile the OP's code, it prints the contents of an integer register that has not been set particularly by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
 float float1, float2; // correct this first
```

Then use the `%f`(float) qualifier

```
printf("Current value float1=%f float2 = %f",float1,float2);
```